# Most related tag (for a tag)

Tags: feature-request, tags

It would be nice if you could see the most related tags for a tag.

Example:

I guess "pandas" is (at least at the moment) the tag which is most often used in combination with "python".

Is this information available somewhere?

Comment: Was writing a query for this, but [someone already made one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75877/related-tags) seemingly as [an answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140913/how-to-get-the-related-tags-with-an-sede-query)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the related tags are shown on the right sidebar when you are browsing questions based on a tag